# how to validate the minimum and maximum characters using javascript?

Tags: visualforce

how to validate the minimum and maximum characters using javascript?.when enter a value less than minimum value need to show error and click the button need to show error where less than minimum value.same as maximum value also.can anybody help me on this... Thanks.

Comment: For questions that are purely based on Javascript, please use [so].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
function checkLength(){
    var textbox = document.getElementById("textbox");
    if(textbox.value.length >= 10 && textbox.value.length <= 100){
        alert("success");
    }
    else{
        alert("make sure the input is minimum 10 characters long")
    }
}
</script>
<input type="text" id="textbox" onkeyup="checkLength()"/>></input>
<input type="submit" name="textboxSubmit" onclick="checkLength()" />
```

Comment: when key press need to show minimum length(minimum 10 characters) and click button also need to show minimum length(minimum 10 characters).when filled 10 minimum length need to hide error where key press or button click

Comment: @user check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for giving answer,but my requirement is when one character enter need to show error message(minimum 10 characters).when filled error need to hide.no need to put alert message.when maximim need to show error message(maximum 100 characters) .can you help me on this.

Comment: @user check my updated answer.

Comment: i need to show error meesage.no need to show alert message.

Comment: @user which error message you want to display. You can use some div and custom css to show custom error message